# How can I get the url of a failed test in codeception (inside the _failed function)

Tags: php, codeception

I can already send an email with the name and error of the failed test (mail gets generated in the _failed function), but I dont know how to get the url of the failed test. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me like this:

$sitelink = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getCurrentUri();

then use $sitelink in your generated mail.